# Canon 450D: whats the number to the right in the viewfinder?

Tags: canon, canon-450d

I have wondered for quite some time now what the number to the outer right in my 450D's viewfinder is.

Example:

30" 2.8 |''|''|''|''| 100 **6**

what's the 6 stand for?

Comment: Number of Frames left? (space on card)

Comment: It's "6" most of the time. No matter how many pictures i've taken. So it can't be related to card space

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you might be asking about the maximum burst number. It tells you how many pictures you can take before the buffer is full. As you take pictures, the number will go down, and it will go back up as the buffer clears to the memory card. Taking pictures closer together (or using continuous) will deplete the buffer faster.

[image]

Comment: good explanation. To be clear: the number would not change if I bought a faster SD card? Because this is about the camera's internal buffer?

Comment: Correct, but the number would return to 6 faster with a faster SD card - up to the maximum speed that your camera supports.